# Liquibase diffChangeLog command generates dropSequence changesets even if the tables are identical, what could be the issue?

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface, liquibase

I have two postgresql tables. **DB_X** and **DB_Y** which is a copy of the first. Now I've made changes to several tables in DB_Y and I wanted to migrate those changes to DB_X using *liquibase diffChangeLog* which results in a db-changelog.xml file.

The db-changelog file has all the changesets for the changes I made in DB_Y but additionally it has *dropSequence* changesets for all tables even the ones I did not change anything.

I'm running the diff command from command line. My liquibase is v3.6.2 PostgreSQL 10.2

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --changeLogFile=D:\db-changelog14May.xml 
--url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_X"  --username=****  --password=**** diffChangeLog 
--referenceUrl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_Y"  --referenceUsername=*****  --referencePassword=*****
```

I expected the the db-changelog.xml file to have only changesets for items I had changed, since I have not changed any primary keys I do not expect any sequence related changesets. What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using any framework to define the database model (e.g. Entity Framework)?

Comment: No, I'm creating the tables directly in the database either via terminal or PGAdmin, then reverse engineering it back to Entities using Hibernate. I think this does not affect liquibaseCLI since it does the diff directly in the DB and not via my Entities.